# Linq Select where if selcted item value == something

Tags: c#, linq, repository

I have a repository of items where they may or may not contain `DateTime` fields `ValidFrom` and `ValidTo`.
I need to select all items where today's date falls between the `ValidFrom` and `ValidTo` dates AND all the items that don't have `ValidFrom` and/or `ValidTo` dates.

I've tried

```
.WhereIf(f.ValidFrom.HasValue, f.ValidFrom.Value.Ticks < DateTime.Now.Ticks)
.WhereIf(f.ValidTo.HasValue, f.ValidTo.Value.Ticks > DateTime.Now.Ticks)
.ToList
```

But the first 'f' does not exist in current context.

I've also tried

```
.WhereIf(f => f.ValidFrom.HasValue, f.ValidFrom.Value.Ticks < DateTime.Now.Ticks)
.WhereIf(f => f.ValidTo.HasValue, f.ValidTo.Value.Ticks > DateTime.Now.Ticks)
.ToList
```

That way the third 'f' does not exist in current context.

Comment: `.WhereIf(f => f.ValidFrom.HasValue, f => f.ValidFrom.Value.Ticks < DateTime.Now.Ticks)` ?

Comment: f => f.ValidFrom.HasValue - cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: From what library is the `WhereIf` method. What are the parameters required for this method? Could it be that one of the parameters just expects a bool and not a Linq function?

Comment: Indeed it does expect a bool instead of a Linq function. So I changed it to ```Where(f => f.ValidFrom.HasValue == false || f.ValidTo.HasValue == false || f.ValidFrom.Value.Ticks < DateTime.Now.Ticks && f.ValidTo.Value.Ticks < DateTime.Now.Ticks)``` and that works.

Comment: Okay, make sure to test the query to see if you need extra round brackets around certain conditions so the order they get checked is correct.